# Question about Coupling of Measures

Tags: measure-theory, optimal-transport, coupling

Let $\pi$ be a coupling of probability measures $\mu,\nu.$ For measurable sets $A,B$ we have 
$$
\pi(A\times B) \leq \mu(A)
$$
and
$$
\pi(A^c \times B^c) \leq \mu(A^c),
$$
Therefore we have
$$
\pi(A\times B) = \mu(A).
$$
Is this argument correct?

Comment: I thought $\pi(A\times B) = \mu(A)$ was part of the definition of coupling. What definition do you use?

Comment: ah ok, I used $\pi(A \times X) = \mu(A),$ where $X$ is the whole space.

Comment: so, is this correct or not? thank you.

Comment: are you asking whether, for any measures $\pi$ on $X\times Y$ and $\mu$ on $X$, the two inequalities $\pi(A\times B) \le \mu(A)$ and $\pi(A^c\times B^c) \le \mu(A^c)$ imply $\mu(A\times B) = \mu(A)$? I don't see why.. The second inequality allows you to deduce only that $\pi(A\times B)+\pi(A\times B^c)+\pi(A^c\times B) \ge \mu(A)$.

Comment: they are probability measures. So the second inequality implies $1 - \pi(A \times B) \leq 1 - \mu(A).$

Comment: It would be correct if $A^{\complement}\times B^{\complement}=(A\times B)^{\complement}$, but that is not the case in general.

Comment: When is this correct?

Comment: Look at what I wrote. $(A\times B)^c = (A\times B) \cup (A^c \times B) \cup (A\times B^c)$. Figure it out from here